# Cannot add an application to the launcher

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, .desktop, alacarte

I've downloaded Eclipse and I want it to be on my fast-launching dash bar but the problem is that, as you all probably know, Eclipse does not install but is inside a normal archive.

So I tried to make my own .desktop file and placed it in `~/.local/share/applications` but it didn't change anything.

So I downloaded alacarte and tried to add a menu element but every time I hit the "OK" button nothing happened (there wasn't anything new on the alacarte list, of course nor on the dash bar).

So what should I do and why nothing I've been doing seemed to work?

Mine .desktop file:

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse\ Java
Comment=Eclipse\ Luna\ do\ pracy\ przy\ Javie
Exec=./~/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse\ Java/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=./~/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse\ Java/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true`
 And the alacartes one:

`[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Eclipse Luna dla Javy
Terminal=false
Name=Eclipse Java
Exec=/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse Java/eclipse/eclipse
Type=Application
Icon=/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse Java/eclipse/icon`

Comment: could you add the content of your home-made .desktop file and / or the `alacarte-made` one? Alacarte removes possible icon extensions in the .desktop file for one thing.

Comment: Okey, I added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues with the desktop file

Taking the alacarte-made desktop file as a starting point (the other one has more issues), there are two lines which are almost certainly critical, and causing your desktop file to be refused by Dash and the Launcher:

- `The Exec=` line:

  ```
  Exec=/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse Java/eclipse/eclipse
  ```

  What you are actually trying to do here is to open a file `Java/eclipse/eclipse` with an executable called `Eclipse`, located in `/home/jantek/Instalki`:

  ```
  Exec=<application> <file>
  ```

  That is probably not what you intended. Instead of the application (`eclipse`), you are referring to what seems to be a directory (`Exec=/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse`).

  Assuming the executable `eclipse` (lowercase) is in the folder `.../Eclipse` (looking at your `Icon=` line, but check it), your `Exec=` line simply should be like:

  ```
  Exec=/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse/eclipse
  ```
- The `Icon=` line:

  Like I mentioned in my comment, Alacarte removes the file extension of any icon you define. Apart from that, just like in the `Exec=` line, the path you are defining is incorrect (why the space?). Your `Icon=` line should look like:

  ```
  Icon=/home/jantek/Instalki/Eclipse/icon.xpm
  ```

  But again, check if the paths to both the eclipse executable and the icon are correct.

If you fix these two lines, your `.desktop` file should work fine.

#### Note:

If the path to your executable or your icon includes foldernames with spaces:

- If it is in the `Exec=` line, put either the whole part after `Exec=` in quotes:

  ```
  Exec="/long/path/to/executable/folder with spaces/eclipse"
  ```

  or just the folder with spaces:

  ```
  Exec=/long/path/to/executable/"folder with spaces"/eclipse
  ```
- In the `Icon=` line, a folder with a space should be fine:

  ```
  Icon=/long/path/to/executable/folder with spaces/icon.xpm
  ```

Comment: The space is because the folder is called "Eclipse Java". I think I'll just change the space to '_'.

Comment: @Jantomedes sorry, I was just editing my answer, I saw you were too, what was the edit? I added information about how to habdle folders with spaces.

Comment: Correcting the typo - you wrote "Exec=..."  instead "Icon=..." when talking about the icon.